# Where can I find the definition of projects.openaiClient?

Tags: android, kotlin, openai-api

The following sample code comes from *OpenAI API client for Kotlin* project.

You can see it at  https://github.com/aallam/openai-kotlin/tree/main/sample/native

I open the sample code with Android Studio, but I can't find where the author define the `implementation(projects.openaiClient)`, I have searched the whole project, could you tell me ?

**build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
}

kotlin {
    val hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
    val isMingwX64 = hostOs.startsWith("Windows")
    val nativeTarget = when {
        hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> macosX64("native")
        hostOs == "Linux" -> linuxX64("native")
        isMingwX64 -> mingwX64("native")
        else -> throw GradleException("Host OS is not supported in Kotlin/Native.")
    }
    nativeTarget.apply {
        binaries {
            executable {
                entryPoint = "main"
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val nativeMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                //implementation("com.aallam.openai:openai-client:<version>")
                implementation(projects.openaiClient)   // Where is projects.openaiClient
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.curl)   // Where is libs.ktor.client.curl
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `openai-client` subproject is located [here](https://github.com/aallam/openai-kotlin/tree/main/openai-client). The include was added in  [`settings.gradle.kts`](https://github.com/aallam/openai-kotlin/blob/main/settings.gradle.kts).

In the sample code the author then used something called [type-safe project accessor](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:type-safe-project-accessors):

> A project name with kebab case (some-lib) or snake case (some_lib)
> will be converted to camel case in accessors: projects.someLib.

This means that the dependency can be added using `projects.openaiClient`.